# Is it safe to extend the length of Blake2b’s keyed hash key?

Tags: algorithm-design, blake2

Blake2b keyed hash variation specifies a maximum key length equal to the digest size. It implements this feature simply concatenating the zero-padded key to a boundary of the block size with the message and then hashing.

I am asking myself: Why this arbitrary key length limit? It is just a concatenation. Allowing arbitrary length keys zero-padded to the block boundary does not add extra complexity to the code nor breaks compatibility with current specification. Are there any security flaws making this slight variation?

Comment: Just a note: you can always use an expanding KDF over the result to create more key material (without, of course, extending the strength of the keying material).